# Nodejs : req.body is empty when i try to upload a img file using jquery - ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am learning nodejs and trying to upload a image file without page reload, i'm using this code below but it does not work. Req.body is empty. Can anyone help me ?

in my ejs file:

``````````````````
`````````````````
<body>
<form action="/" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" id='form-data'>
    <input type="file" name='file' id='file' class='file'>
</form>

<script>

    $(document).on('change', '#file', function () {
        var property = document.getElementById('file').files[0]; 
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', property);
        $.post({
            url: '/',
            type: 'post',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    })

</script>
</body>



`````````````````
``````````````````

This is server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views' , __dirname);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.post('/', (req,res) =>{
   console.log(req.body)
})

app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
   res.render('main');
})
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: where is your "multipart" body parser? read [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) - there's links to middlewares that handle `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your comment , i will research this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I know to achieve what your aiming to do is with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Express doesn't easily handle files on its own, so by bringing multer in as a middleware you easily upload files. take a look at line 5 and see "dest", change that to wherever you want the files to be uploaded to

On line 12 I have added the middleware to the post route, the reason I have passed in 'file' is that the form data key for the file is 'file'

On line 13 I have change console.log from req.body to req.file as you can access the file information from there with multer

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' })
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views' , __dirname);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req,res) =>{
   console.log(req.files)
})

app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
   res.render('main');
})
app.listen(3000);
```

To install multer check out the link I have added or simply type:

```
npm install multer
```

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You need middleware for getting file or images for that  install npm i multer for getting the file

app.js

```
  const multer  = require('multer')
    const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

    app.post('/profile-img', upload.single('profileImage'), function (req, res, next) {
      // req.file is the user profileImage.
      // req.body will hold the other fields, if  any
    })
```

For mutiple images :

```
app.post('/product/images', upload.array('images', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of product images.
  // req.body will contain the other fields, if any
})
```